# PHP Files won't open in browser - only download. What do I need to change to make it work properly?

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, httpd.conf

I have tried reinstalling PHP. PHP is working, and Apache2 is running. I don't know why it's not opening in a browser and displaying normally.

Just so you know - my httpd.conf is empty - and instead I have everything in apache2.conf. This is because I'm using Ubuntu.

Can you help me? I know it's something simple, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: You might get better answers on http://serverfault.com/ for this question.

Answer (score 8):

Have you virtual host on this project?

Are you open php file with http://localhost/file.php or directly like file://...../file.php ?

Comment: Yes! I completely forgot that I needed to open through localhost! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In your apache conf:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Don't forget to restart apache afterwards. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That should be automatically handled during installation.

Comment: Yes. It _should_ be. But since this guy has a problem, it's quite obvious that things didn't quite go as expected.

Comment: Well when you say it like that it makes sense :) Never mind my comment.

Answer (score 5):

In my case there was a modification of the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf by module userdir

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The solution is inside the config file, just comment the lines from `<IfModule mod_userdir>` to `</IfModule>`.

Comment: Seems that you're missing something on the last line?

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you. I did not mark the terms in brackets as code.

Comment: I have also same issue.. but I cant find the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf file please help me..

Comment: Hello @newbie it depends on the distribution you use, where the configuration for `mod_userdir` is located. Perhaps this is part of the file `httpd.conf` which is located usually in `/etc/apache2/` or (RedHat) `/etc/httpd/`.
Perhaps you find it if you grep your `/etc/`-Directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

in terminal.
Assuming you are using php 5 :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using php5 the complete solution would be

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Then

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem, but only when accessing my site's root (e.g. `http://example.com`) - it worked as expected when accessing index.php explicitly (e.g. `http://example.com/index.php`).

The issue was that before creating `index.php`, I had an `index.html` file in the web root, but then I renamed it to `index.html.bak` to '*move it out of the way*'.  Unfortunately, that doesn't move it out of the way.  For whatever reason, Apache will serve that file up with a MIME type of `application/x-trash`.
(As the `/etc/mime.types` file contains a line reading "`application/x-trash                             ~ % bak old sik`")

Maybe that will help someone else who is scratching their head as I was.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem listed above and your suggestion is what fixed it.  Would have never thought.

Answer (score 1):

Also, when moving a site and you encounter this, make sure your .htaccess file doesn't specify a different method handler for php. We ran into this moving a wordpress site for a client.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem - and it was in the .htaccess file I had accidentally downloaded from the live server. Once you've deleted the .htaccess file, you will need to clear your cache to be able to load the .php file in your browser via http://